# MVVMCROSS Jump to First Page or Specific Page

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, mvvmcross

I am relatively new to MVVMCROSS, watched few of Stuart's N+1 videos and I say they are very simple and easy to understand. However, I couldn't find a way to jump across pages backwards. See, what I am trying to accomplish is to skip pages when you click save or finish on the last page of a... somewhat a wizard-type hierarchy. Not sure if this is even possible at all, knowing you could go backwards.

Here are my pages in sequence... [List of Machines] > [Meters] > [Bills] > [Taxes] > [Summary]. The save or finish button would be at the [Summary] page. Once that button is clicked, the user will be redirected back to the [List of Machines] page. Not sure if I am making myself clear, but hopefully this is understandable enough.

In addition, I could design a flat structure navigation but this set of pages is already contained inside one of my tabs. Nested tabs isn't going to be a nice user-experience, don't you think? Or I could be wrong, suggestions on a better way of doing this would be very much appreciated.

By the way, I am implementing this on Xamarin.iOS project.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474865/mvvmcross-navigate-back-multiple-viewmodels-truncate-navigation-stack/17475639#17475639 for some suggestions - if you are ios only then it is pretty straightforward to manipulate the ViewControllers collection on a navigationcontroller -'or to display a set of wizard views in a separate modal navigationcontroller which can then all be removed together by closing the modal.

Comment: Thanks Stuart! Well, we are currently working on iOS but will eventually go for other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UINavigationController derived class you can use the `PopToRootViewController` method to 'jump' back to the first screen.