# MvvmCross clear navigation stack for Xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have trouble when I have to delete navigation stack until to determined page. I couldn’t find any feasible solution without NoHistory option. I can remove some pages which have been opened on main page with nohistory attribute but I need another things.

I can explain my problem better with an example. Imagine that I have 5 different pages and the navigation stack’s state is 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5. Third page should be opened when particular button is pressed on page of 5. Actually the navigation stack’s new state should be 1 > 2 > 3.

How can I apply that operation, please could someone add suggestion for this?

Xamarin Forms version is 3.6.364807
MvvmCross version is 6.2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which version of mvx you are using but if it's one of the last ones you can do:

```
this.navigationService.ChangePresentation(new MvxPopPresentationHint(typeof(MyThirdViewModel));
```

This will pop every viewmodel until the third one.

[Here you have the hint in the repo](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Presenters/Hints/MvxPopPresentationHint.cs)

If you don't have that hint because of using a previous version of mvx you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17474865/6248510) to have an idea of how to implement a custom hint.

HIH

Comment: Thank you @fmaccroni for your answer, your suggestion is working. It seem I'm lucky currently I'm using latest version of MvvmCross(6.2.3)